# An exam`s points dilemma

Tags: probability, optimization, expectation

On July 2 I have an exam, in this exam will be 40 questions in test with 5 variants of answer for each question.

- For each correct answer will be given +1 point.
- For each incorrect answer will be given -0.25 point
- For each blank answer no points will be given.

I have 40 question at all. Firtly I will be given 20 question for first subject then 10 for second subject and last 10 question for another subject. I know first and last subject for 100% but I don't know the second subject at all.

I want know in percentages, what will be the best at second part of exam, have I answer at random or leave all questions with no answer or answer to part of qustions.

Comment: Theory of relativity? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a real world problem or not?

**Consideration 1:** You probably need 24 points to pass . If you know part 1 and 3 completely, you get 30 points. If you guess all answers wrong, in part 2, you get 2.5 points subtraction. You still have 27.5 points left. But what if you make a small mistake in one if the other parts? You can always make a stupid mistake, bringing you very close to the 24 points you need to pass.

**Consideration 2:** The expected value of guessing is $\frac{1}{5} \times 1 - \frac{4}{5} \times 0.25 = 0$. The expected value of not guessing is also 0. So it doesn't matter.

Comment: LOL, 24 points how did you get it?

Comment: @МузаффарШакаров 40 points times 60% = 24 points. Here we sometimes need a 60% or 65% score to pass. Well if it is actually lower (50% = 20 points), then you might as well guess. There is usually one answer that is complete nonsense, raising your chance of success.  But is this a real world problem or not?

Comment: ,In second July will be exam) and i am under anxiety

Comment: Okay, but do you know how many points you need to pass?

Comment: You said 24, and thats exactly

Comment: In that case, I recommend, to not guess, unless you can rule out several answers, and then still, limit it to 2 or 3 answers. Also, you should of course first make the other two parts and check them on errors. Good luck with your exam!

Comment: I find your advice right and I will follow it, Thank a lot

Comment: @МузаффарШакаров Just wondering, did you pass the exam?

Comment: Yes, with 67%, I solved  2 questions from second part and hope to my luck, for others, thx a lot

Comment: @МузаффарШакаров Okay, congratulations with your pass!

Answer (score 3):

For those ten questions, were you to guess completely randomly, you would expect to get $10 \cdot \frac{1}{5} = 2$ questions right and $8$ questions wrong, for a total of $0$ points.

Were you to leave them all blank, you would also get $0$ points. This is probably *by-design*, so no one thinks they will be better off one way or another. Really your choice just comes down to your level of risk-aversion, and whether you want to take a gamble on beating the odds and answering more than $2$ questions right.

By the way this isn't relevant to the [theory of relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity), at all.